# Integration of Oracle product hub and Sales force with web 8

Tags: sdl-tridion, external-integrations

I am looking out for approch on integration of oracle  product hub and Sales force with web 8.  If any body has previous experience please share the road map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Integrating Salesforce with Web8, you may try following blogs (and corresponding community framework)

http://hem-kant.blogspot.in/2016/12/Salesforce-Integration-with-SDLWEB8.html